# i want to write the sql for the month wise and year wise data according to the category displayed in the excel file

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Plese help me to write the sql for the image attached

i want to write the sql for the month wise and year wise data according to the category displayed in the excel file

Comment: Please show what efforts you have made to do this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick up your month and use `explode` for each month and use year and month from exploded array